# Function as a set of pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider $f: A\to B$, where $A=\mathcal P(\{1,3,4\})\setminus\emptyset$, $B=\{1,3,4\}$; $f(X)=\min X$ for each $X$ in $A$, where $\min X$ is the minimum number in the set $X$, e.g. $f(\{4,5\})=\min\{4,5\} = 4$.

Write that function as a set of pairs. Is f one-to-one? Is f onto? Is f invertible? Does f have an inverse function? Compute $f^{-1}(\{3,4\})$.

My initial question is how do I list this function as set of pairs and how would I further one answer the rest of these questions with the pairs?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function (or its graph) is just a set of pairs whose components are the elements of the domain and codomain, $\{(x,f(y)):x\in A\}$. So, in this case,

$$\{\;(\{1\},1),\,(\{3\},3),\,(\{4\},4),\,(\{1,3\},1),\,(\{1,4\},1),\,(\{3,4\},3),\,(\{1,3,4\},1)\;\}.$$

Then you can easily conclude that $f$ is not one-to-one (because multiple elements get mapped to $1$), but that it is surjective and that it does not have an inverse (because it is not one-to-one). Also, $f^{-1}(\{3,4\})=\{\{3\},\{4\},\{3,4\}\}$.

Comment: I may have not formatted it properly but A = Powerset({1,3,4})

Comment: Yes, this is why the first components of the pairs are always subsets of this set, for example $\{1\}$, $\{1,4\}$ etc.

Comment: ahhhh I understand now, Thank you so much I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Could you explain how you computed the inverse function?

Comment: There is no inverse function, because $f$ is not bijective. In this case, $f^{-1}(\{3,4\})$ is not the inverse function, but just a notation for the set of elements which get mapped to either $3$ or $4$, which are $\{3\}$, $\{4\}$, and $\{3,4\}$.

Comment: but wouldn't it just be ({3},{3,4}) because 3 is the min x?

Answer (score 0):

If $f: A\to B$ then $f = \{(a,f(a))|a \in A$.

So for example if $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ via $f(n) = n^2$ then $f = \{(1,1),(2,4), (3,9),......\}$.

Another example is if $A = \{0,2,7,4\}$ and $B=\{1,4,5\}$ and $f(0) = 4; f(2)=1; f(7)=1; f(4)=5$ then $f= \{(0,f(0), (2,f(2)), (7,f(7)), (4,f(4))\} = \{(0,4),(2,1), (7,1), (4,5)\}$.

$f$ is one to one if for any $b\in B$ if you have $(a,b)$ (so that $f(a) = b$) that is the *only* pair with $b$ in the second place.

Example:  $f= \{(0,f(0), (2,f(2)), (7,f(7)), (4,f(4))\} = \{(0,4),(2,1), (7,1), (4,5)\}$ we have $(2,1)$ and $(7,1)$ so $f$ is not 1-1.

But in our first example $f = \{(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),.....\}$ then $f$ *is* one-to-one because if we look at all the second terms we never have two pairs with the same second term.  (Because if the second term is $b=a^2$ then the first term is $a=\sqrt b$ and there is only one natural number that when squared will be $b$.)

$f$ is onto if for every element in $B$ there is a pair where that element is the second term.

Example:  If $f:A=\{0,2,7,4\} \to B=\{4,1,5\}$ with $f= \{(0,f(0), (2,f(2)), (7,f(7)), (4,f(4))\} = \{(0,4),(2,1), (7,1), (4,5)\}$ then for $4\in B$ we have $(0,4)$ and for $1 \in B$ we hae both $(2,1)$ and $(7,1)$ and for $5\in B$ we have $(4,5)$.  So $f$ is onto.

In our second example for $2 \in \mathbb N$ we do not have any $(a,2)$ because $a^2 =2$ is impossible if $a$ is a natural number.  So $f$ is not onto.

Example: $A = \{a,b,c,d\}; B= \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $f=\{(a,3),(b,1), (c,4), (d,2)\}$ is both one-to-one and onto.

But $g:A\to B$ where $g = \{(a,2),(b,4),(c,1), (d,2)\}$ is neither one to one (because we have both $(a,2)$ and $(d,2)$ ) nor is it onto (because we don't have any $(x,3)$.)